# Ubuntu One login error: "org.freedesktop.secret.collection" doesn't exist

Tags: 11.10, ubuntu-one

When I click on Ubuntu One in the launcher and try to log in I get:

> method "createitem" with signature "a{sv}(oyay)b" on interface
>   "org.freedeskto.secret.collection" doesn't exist

I don't have a clue what this means or how to fix it. Can any one offer any help?

I have a clean install of 11.10 on a 20GB partition of a 40GB hard drive. The other 20GB is for Windows XP Professional.

Comment: are you connected to internet?

Comment: Have you joined up on the website or are you trying to do it from within the desktop application? The Ubuntu One website has a very good [help page here](https://one.ubuntu.com/help/) that you should have a read through - it's FAQ section lists most common problems and solutions.

Comment: yes I am connected to internet. i have accesed through fire fox but am trying to acces through i guess the app in the launcher bar on left side of screen. please relize i'm NEW to ubuntu and linux so i have NO clue what I'm doing

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that was recently [fixed](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu-sso-client/+bug/745540).

Comment: I'm new to ubuntu and linux so I'm a bit confused on how to implement on my system

Comment: Sorry, it looks like the [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gnome-keyring/+bug/874501) you're seeing is still being worked on. But it's very _close_.